# Javascript cut string by begin and end and store in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, string, split

I need a algorithm which is doing something like this:

```
var example = "Hello $$user$$ your real name is $$realname$$. Have a good day"
Output --> ["Hello ", "$$user$$", " your real name is ", "$$realname$$", ". Have a good day"]
```

Hence, split the part by a selected character and put them together in a string array. Can someone help me out?

I'm looking for a solution with JavaScript/jQuery

Comment: Please post what have your tried till now.

Comment: Do you have an example of your code to go by? There are many pre-built function that allow what you are looking for like Slice(), Substring(), And Substr(), length() etc. In Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with JavaScript itself... Slightly tricky, but yes.

```js
var strings = [], tokens = [];
var str = "Hello $$user$$ your real name is $$realname$$. Have a good day".replace(/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/g, "\$\$TOKEN$1\$\$").split("$");
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if (str[i].indexOf("TOKEN") === 0) {
    // This is a token.
    tokens.push(str[i].replace("TOKEN", ""));
  } else {
    strings.push(str[i]);
  }
}
str = str.map(function (v) {
  if (v.indexOf("TOKEN") === 0)
    return "$$" + v.replace("TOKEN", "") + "$$";
  return v;
});
console.log(str);
console.log(strings);
console.log(tokens);
```

The above code will split everything into tokens. And on top of it, it also separates the strings and tokens out. The above one gives as per your requirement:

```
[
  "Hello ",
  "$$user$$",
  " your real name is ",
  "$$realname$$",
  ". Have a good day"
]
```

Kindly note, there's nothing like `{value, value}`, there's only `[value, value]`.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you want to split by pattern *$$...$$*; You could use `/(\$\$.*?\$\$)/`; To keep the pattern in the result, you can make it a capture group, and also make it lazy (*?*) so that it will split with the shortest length pattern matched:

```
example.split(/(\$\$.*?\$\$)/)

#[ 'Hello ',
#  '$$user$$',
#  ' your real name is ',
#  '$$realname$$',
#  '. Have a good day' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### String.split()

> The [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method splits a String object into an array of strings by separating the string into substrings.

```js
var example = "Hello $$user$$ your real name is $$realname$$. Have a good day";
var exSplit = example.split("$$");
var userIdx = exSplit.indexOf("user");
var nameIdx = exSplit.indexOf("realname");
document.querySelector(".user").innerHTML = exSplit[userIdx];
document.querySelector(".name").innerHTML = exSplit[nameIdx];
```

```html
<div class="user"></div>
<div class="name"></div>
```

Though, if I may suggest, variables can handle this type of operation without all of the hassle.